# Initializing variables in plugin for use on Wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I created a session plugin in Wordpress so I could send success/error messages after form submissions. It looks something like this:

```
class MySession{
  //do some stuff...
}
$mySession = new MySession();
$sSuccess = $mySession->success();
$sError = $mySession->error();
```

I can use `$mySession` on my actual Wordpress pages but the other two variables don't get initialized. I have to manually insert those last two lines of code in my page. Any idea why or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what you have in success() method?

Comment: So you don't get a parse error...?

Comment: sorry about that, I forgot to put the $ on mySession, but that's not the problem as I did so correctly in my code. and no I don't get a parse error. cutting and pasting those last two lines into my php page template solves the problem, but I'd prefer to put them in my plugin if possible so that I don't have to include them in every page template I want to use session variables in

Answer (score 0):

Change `mySession = new MySession();`

To

```
$mySession = new MySession();
```

then ->

```
$sSuccess = $mySession->success();
$sError = $mySession->error();
```